# how to remove emoji in VBScript

Tags: string, vbscript, character, emoji

I'm new to VBS and my script crashes when the subject of an email contains emoji like this string:

```
=?UTF-8?Q?Follow_Fluff_Festival=2c_Dolto_a=2c_nd_DOLLY_PRANE?=
=?UTF-8?B?8J+Hq/Cfh7finJ4gb24gVHdpdHRlciE=?=
```

I tried:

```
subjet = Replace(oMessage.Subject, (([0-9|#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}|\x{00a9}|\x{203C}|\x{2047}|\x{2048}|\x{2049}|\x{3030}|\x{303D}|\x{2139}|\x{2122}|\x{3297}|\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F6FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]), "")
```

but this doesn't work. How can I remove all emoji characters from a string in VBScript?